# Не получается получить данные из span C# Selenium

Tags: c#, парсер, selenium

```
            var driver = new ChromeDriver();

        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://zapper.fi/account/vitalik.eth");
        try            
        {
            IWebElement _ethAdress = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/main/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div"));
            Console.WriteLine(_ethAdress.Text);
            driver.Quit();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ОШИБКА @#$%$#!" + ex);
            driver.Quit();
```

Сама проблема собсна: пытаюсь получить .text из дива, если спускаюсь на уровень ниже - вообще выдаёт ошибку. скриншот откуда беру xpath - прилагаю.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: 1) использовать XPath от корня неэффективно (и выглядит кошмарно), [оптимизируйте запрос](https://devhints.io/xpath). 2) На момент выполнения запроса нужных элементов еще может не быть на странице, они могут подгружаться через AJAX уже после загрузки страницы, поэтому можно попробовать в код паузу добавить перед запросом. 3) Перед тес как парсить любой сайт стоит поинтересоваться, вдруг у него уже есть API

Comment: По классу увы и ах, пытался, выдавало сразу несколько результатов, пауза помогла, но хочется чтобы сразу после загрузки получалось значение, а не ждать лишние 0.5 сек.
API есть, но хотелось именно практики с Selenium. На данный момент в целом изучаю программирование всего 2 дня :)

Comment: Селениум не для этого создан, он создан для автоматического тестирования сайтов, которые вы разрабатываете. То есть вы заведомо учитесь стрелять по воробьям из пушки, ЭТО ЗАВЕДОМО НЕВЕРНЫЙ ПУТЬ. Для парсинга есть более легковесные способы получения информации. Начать надо с изучения HTTP и как с ним работать и научиться просматривать сетевой лог браузера в инструментах разработчика. То есть получить нужную информацию можно значительно проще всего-лишь отправив нужный запрос на сервер, а не открывая страницу целиком.

Comment: Спасибо за наставление, учту.